# getenv in Visual C++ 2012

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012, extern, getenv

I want to use a `getenv` function from C in my C++ project in Visual Studio 2012.

The code:

```
extern "C" System::SByte^ getenv(const System::SByte^ name);
```

and then in some function:

```
String^ h1 = "HOMEDRIVE";
const System::SByte^ c1 = dynamic_cast<const System::SByte^>(h1);
getenv(c1);
```

The error I get:

```
Error   11  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" class System::SByte ^ __clrcall getenv(class System::SByte const ^)" (?getenv@@$$J0YMP$AAVSByte@System@@P$ABV12@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall Kameleon::Form1::createConfig(void)" (?createConfig@Form1@Kameleon@@$$FQ$AAMXXZ)   C:\Users\Michal\Desktop\Kameleon\Kameleon\Kameleon\Kameleon.obj Kameleon
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to call the C function? There is a managed equivalent:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think for C++ project you can use [`getenv` from `<cstdlib>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv), not C++/CLI one.